# Error while using hyperledger composer with explorer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-explorer

I am trying to use hyperledger composer alongside hyperledger explorer. I've deployed a simple business network on fabric-dev-servers. On the composer side it is working fine and I am able to interact with the network perfectly but when I am trying to integrate it with hyperledger explorer I am getting the following error while starting it.

**console log**

```
postgres://hppoc:password@127.0.0.1:5432/fabricexplorer
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Explorer Error >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined
    at Platform.initialize (/home/paradox/hyperledger/fabric/blockchain-explorer/app/platform/fabric/Platform.js:54:48)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
(node:23248) DeprecationWarning: grpc.load: Use the @grpc/proto-loader module with grpc.loadPackageDefinition instead
Received kill signal, shutting down gracefully
Closed out connections
```

**App log:**

```
[2018-10-29 22:14:30.719] [DEBUG] Platform - ******* Initialization started for hyperledger fabric platform ******
[2018-10-29 22:14:30.719] [DEBUG] Platform - Setting admin organization enrolment files
```

**db log:**

```
[2018-10-29 22:14:22.055] [INFO] pgservice - Please set logger.setLevel to DEBUG in ./app/helper.js to log the debugging.
```

Following is my config.json
**config:**

```
{
  "network-config": {
    "org1": {
      "name": "Org1",
      "mspid": "Org1MSP",
      "peer1": {
        "requests": "grpcs://127.0.0.1:7051",
        "events": "grpcs://127.0.0.1:7053",
        "server-hostname": "peer0.org1.example.com",
        "tls_cacerts": "/home/paradox/hyperledger/fabric/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv12/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
      },
      "admin": {
        "key": "/home/paradox/hyperledger/fabric/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv12/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore",
        "cert": "/home/paradox/hyperledger/fabric/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv12/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts"
      }
    }
  },
  "channel": "composerchannel",
  "orderers": [
    {
      "mspid": "OrdererMSP",
      "server-hostname": "orderer.example.com",
      "requests": "grpcs://127.0.0.1:7050",
      "tls_cacerts": "/home/paradox/hyperledger/fabric/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv12/composer/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
    }
  ],
  "keyValueStore": "/tmp/fabric-client-kvs",
  "configtxgenToolPath": "/home/playground/fabric-samples/bin",
  "SYNC_START_DATE_FORMAT": "YYYY/MM/DD",
  "syncStartDate": "2018/9/01",
  "eventWaitTime": "30000",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "version": 1.0
}
```

Comment: the sample config provided on the Github repo is here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/blob/master/CONFIG-COMPOSER-HLEXPLORER.md  . Comparing your config above to this [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51857102/error-while-starting-hyperledger-explorer-with-hyperledger-composer) you've not got quotes around "version: "1.0" - not sure if it makes a difference anyway if its a float.

Comment: Still no good :(

Comment: you should ask on Rocketchat channel #hyperledger-explorer -> https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/hyperledger-explorer

Comment: I actually [did](https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/hyperledger-explorer?msg=nQKSkEs6EcT6e6kPP) :P

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar kind of issue and solved it using following steps.

1. Download Explorer 3.5 from given url.
   https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/tree/v0.3.5.1
2. Hyperledger Composer Setup(Update config.json)
3. Build Hyperledger Explorer
4. Run Hyperledger Explorer

Finally it work for Fabric 1.2 and Composer@0.20.

I hope it will help you !

Comment: Hi, But according to @Paul the support for fabric 1.2 was only added in v3.7

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the format of your `config.json` file, it looks like you might be either using an old version of Explorer, or an old `config.json`. Support for Fabric 1.2 (which it looks like you are using) was only added in Explorer 3.7, along with changes to the structure of `config.json`.

So, I would recommend the following:

- Update to Explorer 3.7 (branch release-3.7).
- Follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/blob/release-3.7/README.md).

Comment: Okay will look into it..!